# Set data in navbar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap to create navbar. I created a page header at every page. Now client's requirement is to set header at navbar. I am attaching screenshot for this.
As I am using this solution to create a span at navbar and call a jquery method at every page to fill navbar span.

Here is code snippet.

**At navbar**

```
<span class="span5" style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: lighter" id="pageTitle"></span>
```

**At my page**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $("#pageTitle").html('Page Header');
    });
</script>
```

In this implementation I need to call jquery code at all pages. Is there any generic solution for this.

[image: Page header image]

Comment: Are you using any server code? If you are only using pure html/css, you will have to call that on every load.

Comment: I am not using any server code. In my current scenario page header is already implemented at all page.I just need to add a generic solution for this.

Comment: In that case, I think you can only either:
1. change page partially without refreshing the nav bar or
2. call what you have on every page load